# Failed to open module module-equalizer-sink.so:module-equalizer-sink.so:cannot open shared object file:No such file or directory. error coming

Tags: command-line, software-installation, sound, 20.04, pulseaudio

Error coming in logs:

```
 failed to open module "module equalizer-sink" 
 sender: pulse audio
error:Failed to open module module-equalizer-sink.so: module-equalizer-sink.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
 sender: pulse audio.
```

Answer (score 2):

On file level, the *module-equalizer-sink.so* is provided by [`pulseaudio-equalizer` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=module-equalizer-sink.so). You have to install it on 18.04 LTS and newer with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

For 16.04 LTS it is contained in [`pulseaudio` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=module-equalizer-sink.so):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio
```

Comment: iam not able to see the pulseaudio equalizer application..

Comment: Try to launch it as `qpaeq` after installation of the `pulseaudio-equalizer` package.

Comment: But bro...its a different one...i had installed before reinstalling ubuntu  one more pulse audio Equalizer that had too nany options, looks like a yotal package of Equalizer.... basically it had too many options

Comment: its solved...everything fine